# ON CONFLICT (UUid, date_trunc('day', timestamp))

Tags: postgresql

In the code below, that works well, I'd like to get rid of the 'mday' and use only the day part of the timestamp in ON CONFLICT / ON CONSTRAINT yet have found no solution to do so. HAd set my hopes on an exclusion constraint  EXCLUDE (fid WITH =, date_trunc('day', ts) WITH =) but that does not work.

```
BEGIN;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS flow;
CREATE TABLE flow ( 
    fid  UUid NOT NULL,
    fvol REAL[],
    ts   TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    mday DATE NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (fid, mday)
);
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO flow (fid, fvol, ts, mday)
VALUES (
    'b55e9fbe-daea-4142-8843-5e5cf757b778', '{7}',
    '2019-06-26T19:12:00Z01', '2019-06-26'
)
ON CONFLICT (fid, mday)
DO UPDATE
SET fvol = flow.fvol || EXCLUDED.fvol, ts = EXCLUDED.ts;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a unique constraint on an expression (e.g. `unique (fid, (ts::date))` and you can't create a unique index with it either (which would be enough for an `ON CONFLICT`).

The unique index will be rejected with:

> ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE

This is because (for some internal Postgres reasons) the casting of a timestamp to a `DATE` is not considered unambiguous. But you can get around this limitation by creating an immutable function that does this.

```
create function my_to_date(p_ts timestamp with time zone) 
  returns date
as $$
  select p_ts::date;
$$ 
language sql
immutable; --<< this makes the function usable in an index
```

Once you have that, you can create a unique index on the expression:

```
create unique index ix_unique_day on flow (fid, my_to_date(ts));
```

Note that you can not create a unique *constraint* with that index, but for your purpose this does not matter.

The expression of the unique *index* can be used in the `ON CONFLICT` part:

```
INSERT INTO flow 
  (fid, fvol, ts)
VALUES 
  ('b55e9fbe-daea-4142-8843-5e5cf757b778', '{7}', '2019-06-26T19:12:00Z01')
ON CONFLICT (fid, my_to_date(ts))
DO UPDATE
  SET fvol = flow.fvol || EXCLUDED.fvol, ts = EXCLUDED.ts;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for timestamp without timezone, with timezone it nags about not being immutable. The principle how to do such a thing is clear to me now.